# Sass Conditionals Based on Environment Setting

Tags: sass, compass-sass

In a Compass `config.rb` file, you can set the `environment` to `:development` or `:production`.

Is it possible to use this setting in Sass conditionals? Here's what I want to do:

```
@if (environment === :development) {
    @import 'debug';
}
```

**Solved:** I found the answer while drafting my question. Will post anyway since I didn't find anything definitive that actually explains this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks in part to [this issue](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/987) in the Compass repository, I found that you can use settings-based conditionals in Sass like this:

```
@if compass-env() == 'development' {
    body {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Confirmed this works with Sass 3.2.5 + Compass 0.12.2 + Ruby 1.9.3p194.

However you can't do this:

```
@if compass-env() == 'development' {
    @import 'debug';
}
```

That throws a Syntax Error: "Import directives may not be used within control directives or mixins.

So the workaround is to `@import` the file and then wrap its entire contents in the environment conditional.

Answer (score 1):

This can done (when Compass is not available) by storing environment information in an dynamically generated SCSS file, which can then be imported wherever this information is required. This should be done before the SASS compiler is started.

Here's what the build script can look like (i.e. `build.sh`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "\$ENV: 'production';" > ./_sass/env.scss

../node_modules/.bin/node-sass ./_sass/style.scss   ../_site/css/style.css --source-map=true
```

This SCSS file can the be used like so:

```css
@import 'env';

@if ($ENV == 'production') {
   ...
   // some SCSS styling to be used in production only
   ...
}
```